# Is that possible to read data from Database into Config.groovy?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, grails-3.0

I need to to read data from database to be read into Config.groovy.

Is that possible to get data from Database into Config.groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. In the sequence of events when a Grails application is starting up the Config.groovy is processed before the Datasource is made available to the application.

Without knowing what you are trying to accomplish I can't make a suggestion on how else to approach this issue.

**Updated (based on comment)**

In your comment you explain that you are trying to use the feature switch plugin (which is designed to be run time and not persistent). Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/antony/grails-feature-switch/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/uk/co/desirableobjects/featureswitch/FeatureSwitchAdminController.groovy) for the plugin you should be able to make your own service that will load the settings from the database and toggles/updates the feature switch settings. Here is just a simple sketch/example:

```
package example

import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean

class MyExampleService implements InitializingBean {
  def grailsApplication
  void afterPropertiesSet() {
    // here is where you would do whatever you needed to load the settings
    grailsApplication.config.features['somefeature'].enabled = true
    grailsApplication.config.features['otherfeature'].enabled = false
  }
}
```

That should at least give you an idea.

Alternatively you could just write it all in `Bootstrap.groovy` which can access the datasource/GORM as well.

Comment: Well, there is a Feature Switch Plugin for grails (https://github.com/antony/grails-feature-switch/blob/master/README.markdown) ... But it's not persistent, so every time I restart the server, the value goes to the default value. I wanted to make this plugin persistent. The problem is that it's configured into Config.groovy... Do you have some link with that information you said about Config getting processed before datasource?

Comment: I saw your update. It really worked. Thank you so much! Is there anyway to override the Controller? Because now I need to update the database when user toggle the feature from the screen they provide from localhost:8080/your-app/admin/features

Comment: That's another question, but yes. You can simply create a controller in your application with the same name and package and it will override the one in the plugin. That way you can replace it with whatever you want.

Comment: It worked. Thank you! I created a new Controller overriding the plugin's one and modified the modifyFeature method. Problem solved! :-)